# Ingresar datos de textArea sin omitir los espacios a la bd

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Buen dia tengan, como puedo realizar para que al meter datos en mi text area con espacios, se ingrese a la bd de la misma forma, ya que como lo ingreso a la hora de guardarse en la bd, omite los espacios y al querer mostrarlo en su lugar correspondiente, me lo muestra todo junto.. anexo fotos para que se den una idea de lo que ocurre

[image: Mi te]

Mi textArea le inserto los datos asi y los guardo pero a la hora de mostrarlo en un card me los muestra asi sin espacios...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quisiera que se ingrese como en el textarea para que se visualice la misma forma...

**edit**

anexo los codigos correspondientes para guardar y el otro para visaualizar

```
<form method="post" action="services/guardarAreaEditada.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $res['idArea']; ?>">
    
            <!-- <label for="idperfil">id Area:</label>
            <input value="<?php echo $res['idArea'] ?>" class="form-control" name="idArea" required type="text" id="idArea" placeholder="id del Area"> -->

            <label for="nombre">Nombre de Area:</label>

            <input value="<?php echo $res['nombreArea'] ?>" class="form-control" name="areaName" required type="text" id="areaName" placeholder="Escriba el nuevo nombre del area">

            <label for="descripcion">Descripcion del area:</label>
            <!-- <input value="<?php echo $res['descripcionArea'] ?>" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="1" name="areaDesc" required type="text" id="areaDesc" placeholder="Escriba la nueva descripcion del area"> -->

            <textarea class="form-control" name="areaDesc" required  id="areaDesc" placeholder="Escriba la nueva descripcion del area"  cols="30" rows="5"><?php echo $res['descripcionArea'] ?></textarea>

            <label for="imagenPortada">Imagen de portada actual:</label> <br>
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="images/<?php echo $res['imagenPortada']?>" style="width: 200px;">
    <?php } ?>
            <label for="imagenPortada">Seleccione nueva imagen de portad:</label> <br>
            <input type="file" required id="imagenPortadaact" name="imagenPortadaact" cols="30" rows="1" class="form-control-file " placeholder="Descripcion de perfil"></input>

            
            <br><CENTER><input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Guardar">

            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="areasdelsistema.php">Cancelar</a></CENTER>
        </form>
```

php para guardar

```
include '../database/db.config.php';
$fecha= date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".date("d");

$idArea = $_POST["idArea"];
$areaName = $_POST["areaName"];
$areaDesc = $_POST["areaDesc"];
$nombrearea='areas';
$tiporegistro='ACTUALIZAR';

$archivo=$_FILES["imagenPortadaact"];
$extension = pathinfo($archivo["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$imagen=$areaName."-edit-".$fecha.".".$extension;

move_uploaded_file($archivo["tmp_name"], "../images/$imagen");
// $imagenPortada = $_POST["imagenPortada"];


// $sentencia = DBC::get()->prepare("UPDATE areas SET nombreArea = ?, descripcionArea = ?, imagenPortada = ? WHERE idArea = ?;");
// $resultado = $sentencia->execute([$areaName, $areaDesc, $imagen, $idArea]);
if($varProfile != 1){
    //invitado
            $stmt = $conex->prepare("SELECT * FROM modareas WHERE idarea = ?;");
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $idArea);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt -> get_result();
            $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;

    if($num_of_rows<1){                 
        //  La búsqueda no arrojó usuarios con ese ID, por lo tanto el usuario no existe                
        $stmt = $conex->prepare("INSERT INTO modareas (nombretabla,tiporegistro,idarea,nombrearea,descripcionarea,imagenarea) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
        $stmt->bind_param('ssisss',$nombrearea, $tiporegistro,$idArea, $areaName,$areaDesc,$imagen);
        $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt == TRUE){
                header("Location: ../areasdelsistema.php");  
                exit;
            }
            else{echo "Algo salió mal. Por favor verifica que la tabla exista";}

        exit();
        }else {
            $stmt = $conex->prepare("UPDATE modareas SET tiporegistro = ?, nombrearea=?, descripcionarea=?, imagenarea=? WHERE idarea=?;");
            $stmt->bind_param('ssssi',$tiporegistro,$areaName,$areaDesc,$imagen,$idArea);
            $stmt->execute();
        
                if($stmt == TRUE){
                    header("Location: ../areasdelsistema.php");  
                    exit;
                }
                else echo "Algo salió mal. Por favor verifica que la tabla exista";     
            }   
        }
    else{
        //administrador
        $stmt = $conex->prepare("UPDATE areas SET nombreArea = ?, descripcionArea = ?, imagenPortada = ? WHERE idArea = ?;");
        $stmt->bind_param('sssi',$areaName,$areaDesc,$imagen,$idArea);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt == TRUE){
            header("Location: ../areasdelsistema.php");  
            exit;
        }
        else echo "Algo salió mal. Por favor verifica que la tabla exista";
        }
?>
```

Comment: @Excorpion ahora si ya lo anexe

Comment: A menos que los elimines, los saltos de línea se mantienen; si el problema es solo al mostrarlos, te recomiendo usar [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php).